# Mongodb update value inside array inside another array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need update all documents where the value inside an array inside another array ("days.Hour") is "08h" to "8".

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5bbd1396197aa5389cb7bfb7"),
"days" : [ 
    {
        "Day" : "Saturday",
        "Hour" : [ 
            "08h", 
            "10h"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "Day" : "Sunday",
        "Hour" : [ 
            "08h", 
            "10h"
        ]
    }
],
"name" : "Guilherme",
"isActive" : true,
"gender" : "male"
}
```

I tried to do a foreach, but without success:

```
myCollection.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.days.forEach(function(day) {
        day.Hour.forEach(function(hour) {
            hour = hour.replace("h", "");                
            print(hour);
        });
    });
    // Here I can replace the document, but the document doesn't contain my replace
    print(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Read, manipulate data in code & writing it back for n number of docs is not preferred, You can actually try this query:

```
myCollection.updateMany({
}, { $set: { "days.$[].Hour.$[eachHour]": '8h' } }, {
    arrayFilters: [{ 'eachHour': '08h' }]
})
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbd1396197aa5389cb7bfb7"),
    "days" : [ 
        {
            "Day" : "Saturday",
            "Hour" : [ 
                "08h", 
                "10h"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Day" : "Sunday",
            "Hour" : [ 
                "08h", 
                "10h"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Guilherme",
    "isActive" : true,
    "gender" : "male"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f085ad02e05b69487f2b3"),
    "days" : [ 
        {
            "Day" : "Saturday",
            "Hour" : [ 
                "18h", 
                "10h"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Day" : "Sunday",
            "Hour" : [ 
                "08h", 
                "10h"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Guilherme2",
    "isActive" : true,
    "gender" : "male"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f0865d02e05b69487f3a0"),
    "days" : [ 
        {
            "Day" : "Saturday",
            "Hour" : [ 
                "18h", 
                "10h"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Day" : "Sunday",
            "Hour" : [ 
                "18h", 
                "10h"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Guilherme3",
    "isActive" : true,
    "gender" : "male"
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbd1396197aa5389cb7bfb7"),
    "days" : [ 
        {
            "Day" : "Saturday",
            "Hour" : [ 
                "8h", 
                "10h"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Day" : "Sunday",
            "Hour" : [ 
                "8h", 
                "10h"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Guilherme",
    "isActive" : true,
    "gender" : "male"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f085ad02e05b69487f2b3"),
    "days" : [ 
        {
            "Day" : "Saturday",
            "Hour" : [ 
                "18h", 
                "10h"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Day" : "Sunday",
            "Hour" : [ 
                "8h", 
                "10h"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Guilherme2",
    "isActive" : true,
    "gender" : "male"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e2f0865d02e05b69487f3a0"),
    "days" : [ 
        {
            "Day" : "Saturday",
            "Hour" : [ 
                "18h", 
                "10h"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "Day" : "Sunday",
            "Hour" : [ 
                "18h", 
                "10h"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Guilherme3",
    "isActive" : true,
    "gender" : "male"
}
```

It updates two documents.

**Ref :** [.updateMany()-arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
day.Hour.forEach(function(hour){
    let newHour = hour.replace("h", "");                
    print(newHour);
})
```

Comment: Inside the "day.Hour" forEach function I have the newHour. But How can I replace the document with the "newHour" value?

Comment: I think you just do: 
`day.Hour.forEach(function(hour){
    hour.replace("h", "");                
})`